# Real Life Examples of Currying and Partial Function

Tags: scala, currying

I'm new to Scala and recently studying Currying. I know what is currying and partially applied function. But I don't understand why to use Currying instead of multiple parameters. So can any body please help me by providing some e.g. of currying.

Comment: Did you mean "partially applied functions"? Note that "partial functions" are also a thing, but it's something completely different.

Comment: is "Raman Mishra" the same user as "user8340003"?

Comment: I'm not raman mishra

Comment: @AndreyTyukin why you’ve asked so? Is there any problem? I just edited it because it has some grammatical mistakes.

Comment: @RamanMishra I guess it was the edit in combination with the clarification request in the comments under the answer, I didn't expect to get any follow-up questions from another user.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "currying" you mean function definitions with multiple argument lists, the two most important advantages are:

1. Better type inference: types of the arguments in previous argument lists can be used for type inference of arguments in later argument lists. This here works:

   ```
   def delta[A](x: A)(f: A => A): A = f(x)
   delta(5)(x => x)
   ```

   but this here doesn't:

   ```
   def foo[A](x: A, f: A => A): A = f(x)
   foo(5, x => x) // error: missing parameter type
   ```

   Most prominent example of this is probably `fold` on lists:

   ```
   val a = List(1, 2, 3)
   a.foldLeft("List:"){ (s, i) => s + " " + i }
   ```

   No need to ascribe the types to `s` and `i` in this example.
2. You can use variables from previous argument lists to define default parameters:

   ```
   def f(x: Int)(y: Int, z: Int = x * x) = x + y * z // valid
   f(2)(3) // works

   def g(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int = x * x) = x + y * z // invalid
   ```

---

By "partially applied functions", one usually means something like this:

```
List(83,223,314,56,79).map(math.min(100, _))
// output: List(83, 100, 100, 56, 79)
```

Here, the mathematical function `min` is first used to create a partially applied function `min(100, _)`, which is then passed to `map` to truncate all numbers greater than 100 in the list.

If you instead meant "partially applied curried functions", then here is the same example with a curried function:

```
def min(x: Int)(y: Int) = x min y
List(83,223,314,56,79).map(min(100))
```

As you can see, the curried version is even shorter and more concise than the usual "partial applied function"-version.

I'm not sure what to say about the "advantages" of partially applied functions, except that you can use them, and that not being able to use them is pain.

Comment: That’s a nice example but, I would like to know some really time example or may be business problems where we can use currying.

Comment: @RamanMishra I'm not sure what you mean by "business problems". The `foldLeft` is a fundamental list operation that is used over and over and *over* in thousand different applications and libraries, so it is as real of a business as it can possibly get.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the answer.